# Why does my ajax cross domain GET return an error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to retrieve the HTTP header response for a cross domain image URL like so:

```
        var image = "https://assets.bwbx.io/images/users/iqjWHBFdfxIU/izgwruSFWIvA/v1/1200x621.jpg"
        $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           crossDomain: true,
           headers: {  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': image },
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           url: image,
           success: function(jsondata){
            console.log("Image is successful");
           },
           error: function(jsondata){
             console.log("Image is unsuccessful " + JSON.stringify(jsondata));
           }
        });
```

I do get the jsondata returned, but it is following the error portion of the ajax request despite being successful.

```
Image is unsuccessful {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be nice if whoever down voted would explain why you are down voting so I can improve my question.

Comment: If you're receiving .jpg image data, then it's not JSONP so `dataType: 'jsonp'` is categorically wrong. Also, access-control-allow-origin headers must be set on the server, not on the client. CORS would be completely useless if the client would be able to circumvent it that easily.

Comment: And `crossDomain` is only used to simulate cross domain requests on same domain. Read docs

Comment: Why do you need ajax request for an image in the first place?

Comment: I thought I could use ajax to test whether or not cross domain GET was allowed at the resource. I'm pulling meta tags from an off server resource using nodejs. One of them is 'og:image'. Then I am passing the url from that tag to the client and displaying it in <img src=url>. Some sites allow it, some don't because of CORS. I want to know when CORS blocks the request and simply not display the image.

Comment: Ok, so this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Maybe post a new question asking how to do what you're really trying to do.

Comment: I'm starting to realize that :)..When I posted that question, it got downvoted and I was scolded for not understing CORS. Which makes this an XZ process.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of comments, hopefully you will find the answer among them..

- [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) is a response header, not a request header. It would be a header set by the server returning the image, in this case. See the [MDN CORS documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for more info on this topic.
- You seem to be expecting JSON in this response, yet you are requesting an image. You may want to rethink your use-case here.
- You mentioned in the comments that you are trying to "test whether or not a cross domain GET was allowed" - I think your test has proven that it is not allowed .